Can this closed form not exist on the sphere?
This is part (b) to a problem that I solved part (a) for a while back. I finally had time to complete part (b), and I wanted to know if this is a valid answer (proved correctly):

Problem Statement:
The unit sphere is defined as
$$ S^2 = \{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\} \subset \mathbb R^3$$ and $ i : S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is inclusion map. Have form $$ \omega = \left( x^2 - x + yz\right) dy \wedge dz$$
on $\mathbb R^3$.
(a) (solved): Calculate $\int \limits_{S^2} \omega$
Solution: $-4 \pi / 3$
(b) (to be solved): Construct a closed form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb R^3$ such that $i^* \alpha = i^* \omega$, or show that such a form $\alpha$ does not exist.

We'll use a contradiction proof to show that $\alpha$ can't exist.
Suppose $d\alpha = 0$. The pullback is linear when the scalars are real numbers. Thus, $$i^{*}d \alpha = d i^{*}\alpha = 0$$
Also, for any compact oriented manifold $M$,
$$\int \limits_M 0 = 0 $$
Now, diffeomorphisms such as $i$ preserve the boundary. Using Stokes theorem, and noting that $S^2 = \partial B^3$, we have that
$$0 = \int \limits_{iB^3} d(i^{*}
 \alpha) = \int \limits_{iB^3} d(i^{*}
 \omega)  = \int \limits_{iS^2} i^{*} \omega = \int \limits_{S^2} \omega =  -{4 \pi \over 3}$$
but this is clearly absurd. QED

The notation $iB^3$ doesn’t make sense, but yes this is roughly the idea; Stokes’ theorem would give a contradiction.

@peek-a-boo How about this? When $\alpha$ is a closed two-form on all of $\mathbb R^3$ it is exact and there exists a one-form $\eta$ such that $\alpha=d\eta,.$ Then $i^\omega=i^\alpha=i^d\eta=d(i^\eta),.$ That is: $i^\omega$ is exact. This is however not possible because in part one OP has shown that the integral of $\omega$ over $S^2$ is not zero. This contradicts Stokes' theorem: $-3\pi/4=\int_{S^2}\omega=\int_{S^2}i^\omega=\int_{\partial S^2}i^*\eta=0$ because $\partial S^2=\emptyset,.$

@KurtG. sure, but you don’t need to invoke Poincare’s lemma. What OP did is fine and would work even if $\alpha$ was merely a closed $2$-form on an open set $U\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ containing $S^2$ (e.g. an annulus; and here Poincare’s lemma would not be applicable); I was just picking on the notation $iB^3$.

I suggest you just write
\begin{align}
0=\int_{B^3}d\alpha=\int_{\partial B^3}\alpha=\int_{S^2}\alpha=\int_{S^2}\omega=-\frac{4\pi}{3}.
\end{align}
Or if you want to be fully precise, you’re going to need to introduce many more injections. Let $\iota_1:S^2\to\Bbb{R}^3,\iota_2:B^3\to\Bbb{R}^3,\iota_3:S^2\to B^3$ be the canonical injections. Then, we have
\begin{align}
0&=\int_{B^3}\iota_2^*(d\alpha)\tag{$\alpha$ is closed}\\
&=\int_{B^3}d(\iota_2^*\alpha)\\
&=\int_{\partial B^3}\iota_3^*(\iota_2^*\alpha)\tag{Stokes’ theorem}\\
&=\int_{S^2}(\iota_2\circ\iota_3)^*\alpha\\
&=\int_{S^2}\iota_1^*\alpha\\
&=\int_{S^2}\iota_1^*\omega\tag{hypothesis}\\
&=-\frac{4\pi}{3}.
\end{align}
